# Seeking all Roads in Ohio?

Tags: usa

I'm looking for a layer with every road in the state of Ohio in order to create drive-time polygons. I'm not familiar with Ohio data sources. Could anyone point me in the direction of a shapefile with all roads in Ohio, or even all roads in the Cleveland area?

Answer (score 3):

The US Census Bureau is a source of this data and may be found [here](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php). Just select Roads and then Ohio, and road type and you will be able to download the shapefiles.

Comment: The TIGER/line files work well, and openstreetmap.org is a good other resource (I believe they've imported the TIGER files).

Comment: My recollection is the OSM for the United States is originated from the original 2005 release of the Census Bureau's TIGER files and has been crowd-sourcing the improvement of that initial template ever since.

Answer (score 1):

The state government provides a dataset with all roads, and even includes speed limit as an attribute:
https://gis.dot.state.oh.us/tims/Data/Download

Answer (score 0):

If the census data is too old, you might be able to fill in from the state's resources.
http://www.dot.state.oh.us/districts/D01/PlanningPrograms/gis/Pages/default.aspx